# jQuery rotateX in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari

Long time listener first time caller

I've got a transform I need to enable in jQuery. I have a bunch of divs with the class 'piece' when I hover on one they should straighten out. And they do. However when I call the below function all the divs with the 'piece' class before the target lose the parent perspective until the transition is finished. Works fine in Chrome, but not safari. Anyone know a work around?

in action here: 
http://naivemedia.com/test/

Thanks in advance!

```
$('.piece').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotateX(0deg)');
  }, function() {
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotateX(-15deg)');
  }
);
```

Comment: My suggestion is do it in css, it's faster and more reliable compared to js. All you're doing with jQuery is setting a css attribute, and `$('.piece').hover` is equal to `.piece:hover` in css, so you can use `.piece:hover { transform: rotateX(0deg); }`. Also you're already using `transition` attribute, which makes it an animation. Make sure you're adding vendor prefixes or let [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) take care of this. If you can't figure it out, set up a jsfiddle with current code and I'll help.

Comment: Maremp thank you for looking, and the advice.  Much appreciated.  I tried the CSS route.  Still had the issue.  I rebuilt a quick version (css) in a fiddle. And it works. Which might be worse. As it means something else in my code is causing this.  Thanks again.  I may ask a follow up.

http://jsfiddle.net/enderfiles/kkd5e7gy/